# PHP referring to a key value at an index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, smarty

Hey I've got an array of "quantities" from my form:

```
<tr>
                            <td class="col1"> Products </td>
                            <td class="col2">

                                <!-- Interests is an array of all interests in the database-->
                                {foreach $products as $product}
                                <select name="quantities[]" id ="quantities">
                                        {section name=quantities start=0 loop=$product.stock + 1 step=1}
                                        <option value="{$smarty.section.quantities.index}">{$smarty.section.quantities.index}</option>
                                        {/section}
                                </select>
                                {$product.name}<br>
                                {/foreach}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

This is passed into the method:

```
function add_order($customer, $delivery_address, $quantities)
{
    $connection = mysql_open();
    $customer = mysql_escape_string($customer);
    $delivery_address = mysql_escape_string($delivery_address);

    $query = "insert into SEOrders (name, address, status) " .
             "values ('$customer', '$delivery_address', 'New')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or show_error();

    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    $products = get_products();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
    {
        if ($quantities[$i] > 0)
        {
            $product_id = $products[$i]['id'];
            $quantity = $quantities[$i];

            $query2 = "insert into SEOrder_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) " .
                    "values ($id, $product_id, $quantity)";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection) or show_error();
        }
    }

    mysql_close($connection) or show_error();
    return $id;
}
```

I then get an error on this line:

```
$query2 = "insert into SEOrder_items (order_id, product_id, quantity) " .
             "values ('$id', '$product_id', '$quantity')";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query, $connection) or show_error();
```

The error is:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): 4 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /net/SE/includes/defs.php on line 49 Error :
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: `$connection` is not a valid connection resource. Check your `mysql_open()` function

Comment: @deceze: A "singleton" for mysql connection? ;-)

Comment: what's there in mysql_open(). I guess its not returning db link refrence

Comment: @zerkms `return 4; // randomly chosen by dice roll`? ;o)

Comment: @deceze: lol )) /me turned off `mod_telepathy`

Comment: This is a bit weird if `$connection` works for `mysql_query($query, $connection)` but not for `mysql_query($query2, $connection)`. As @zerkms suggests, check `mysql_open()` to ensure it's returning a valid MySQL resource. You might also have to check that the resource is not being closed/modified by `get_products()`. Inserting another `$connection = mysql_open();` above your `for` might help.

Comment: Sidenote: use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

`$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');`

not

`$connection = mysql_open();`

Comment: That works the exact same. mysql_open() is a function defined in another file. This is to secure access to the database as far as I know.

Comment: function mysql_open() {
  $connection = @ mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD)
      or die("Could not connect");
  mysql_select_db(DATABASE, $connection)
      or show_error();
  return $connection;
}

DATABASE, HOST, USER and PASSWORD are defined in a separate PHP file.